# Passbook generates PKPass error

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios6, passbook

I add passbook in my app, when the system is iOS6.0 it work correctly.When the system is iOS7.1 it appear an error.

[image]

I check the code found that

```
PKPass *newPass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:passData error:&error];
```

When generate PKPass in iOS6.0 get a correct PKPass,when the system is iOS7.1 get a nil.

The error contain message is that:

Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid." UserInfo=0x175cd2f0 {NSUnderlyingError=0x175c2c10 "more than one field has the key 'phone'. Field keys must be unique.", NSLocalizedDescription=The pass cannot be read because it isn’t valid.}

The data of the passbook i get it from server.Code like follow

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
[self.connectionData appendData:data];
}
```

After get the data write to file,code like follow:

```
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString* filePath  = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pk.pkpass"];

if ([self.connectionData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]) {

    if (![PKPassLibrary isPassLibraryAvailable]) {

        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                     message:@"PassKit not available"
                                                    delegate:nil
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"Pitty"
                                           otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        return;
    }
}
```

After write to file i want to show it,code like follow:

```
    NSString* passFile = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];

NSString * newPassStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:passFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSData *passData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:passFile];

NSError* error = nil;
PKPass *newPass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:passData error:&error];
```

Then when i get the PKPass *newPass appear the error in iOS7.1. In iOS6 it's OK.

Anyone can tell me the reason?A lot of thanks.

Comment: Most likely you have not included a signing date in your signature.  Can you post the .pkpass bundle?

Comment: @PassKit how to post the pkpass?

Comment: Put it online somewhere and post a link.  How are you populating your `passData` variable?

Comment: @PassKit i post it here http://pan.baidu.com/s/1ntHQPJj thank you!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the pass, so most likely your objective-c code.  How are you populating your `passData` variable?  What information is contained in your `error` variable?

Comment: @PassKit i had edit the question, add some information.Hope that are use for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error message is telling you everything you need to know.

You have duplicate keys in your pass.json.  Your `backFields` array and your `auxiliaryFields` array both contain an item with the key `phone`.  According to the [Passbook Package Format Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PassKit_Bundle/Chapters/Introduction.html), field keys have to be unique.

I notice that this pass has been generated using Passsource.  You might want to let [kudit](http://twitter.com/kudit) (the Passsource developer) know because his service should not allow such a pass to be generated.

Comment: Yes you are right, i overlooked the error message, the different system attracted my attention.

Comment: Looks like the rules are enforced differently across versions.  Also I noted that there was no error thrown when loading the pass via Safari, but it will not load via Chrome, so it looks like the check only applies when initiating a pass using the iOS7 SDK.